# How cast different SwiftUI View structs in a ForEach to display?

Tags: swiftui

I want to display different type of View depending on what is assigned to the items.
Each relevant views conforms to this protocol:

```
public protocol ItemDisplayer {
    init(item: ItemObject)
}
```

This struct stores the Item object and its associated appearance View object.

```
public struct ItemWithDisplay {
    private let item:  ItemObject
    private let itemDisplayer : ItemDisplayer
    
    public init(item : ItemObject, displayer : ItemDisplayer) {
        self.item = item
        self.itemDisplayer = displayer
    }
    
    public func getDisplayer() -> TimeCounterDisplayer {
        return itemDisplayer
    }

    public func getItem() -> ItemObject {
        return item
    }
}
```

There is a few type of View which show the data some kind of way, depends on what was assigned to ItemObject.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OtherItemView: View, ItemDisplayer {
    private var item: ItemObject

    init(item: ItemObject) { self.item = item }

    var body: some View { ... }
}

struct DefaultItemView: View, ItemDisplayer {
    private var item: ItemObject

    init(item: ItemObject) { self.item = item }

    var body: some View { ... }
}
// other ItemViews ...
```

I'd like to seperate the items with views in the modelView class, something like this:

```
switch displayerType {
case .other:
    self.itemWithDisplayArray.append(ItemWithDisplay(item: item, displayer: OtherItemView(itemToDisplay: item)))
case .another:
    self.itemWithDisplayArray.append(ItemWithDisplay(item: item, displayer: AnotherItemView(itemToDisplay: item)))
default:
    self.itemWithDisplayArray.append(ItemWithDisplay(item: item, displayer: DefaultItemView(itemToDisplay: item)))
}
```

This was the information required for the question below.
My question concerns the following section:

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(viewModel.itemWithDisplayArray, id: \.itemId) { item in
        VStack {
            //item.getDisplayer() as! DefaultItemView // It works
           item.getDisplayer() as! AnyView // Cast from 'ItemDisplayer' to unrelated type 'AnyView' always fails // how could I fix this?
        }
    }
}
```

The cast works if the ItemDisplayer casts directly to the DefaultTimerView, or OtherItemView... but I'd like to cast to any View type.

**EDIT:** I've made like this in UIKit:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let itemViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemViewCell
    let itemWithDisplay = itemWithDisplayArray[indexPath.row]
    itemViewCell.containerView = UIView(frame: itemViewCell.contentView.frame)
    itemViewCell.containerView!.addSubview(itemWithDisplay.getDisplayer() as! UIView) // <--the POINT is here: "as! UIView"
    itemViewCell.contentView.addSubview(itemViewCell.containerView!)
    itemWithDisplay.display()
    
    return itemViewCell
}
```

Or in Cocoa:

```
class ItemGridNSView : NSView {
    private let itemWithDisplay : ItemWithDisplay
    
    init(frame frameRect: NSRect, itemWithDisplay: ItemWithDisplay) {
        self.itemWithDisplay = itemWithDisplay
        super.init(frame:frameRect);
        self.addSubview(itemWithDisplay.getDisplayer() as! NSView) // <-- Here too
        itemWithDisplay.display()
    }
...
```

I'm looking for same solution in SwiftUI.

I want to keep the independence of the domain layer from view logic, i.e. any view specific information (import SwiftUI).
I want to avoid this sorting logic in the View layer.

Could you help me please with this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: SwiftUI doesn’t work that way. What you are doing is the exact opposite of having independence between the domain and the View. You are quite literally putting the view in the domain. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). Also, the use of AnyView was heavily discouraged by Apple this year.

Comment: @loremipsum Not 'heavily discouraged'. Just saying that you should avoid it when possible and know its effects, but sometimes you may need it. [See what the engineers said](https://www.swiftui-lab.com/random-lessons#coding-1)

Comment: I stand by my interpretation. You link says when there is no other solution and when the view rarely or never changes.

Comment: @loremipsum You are not right that the view links to the domain layer. Thats why I intend to use a protocol without importing SwiftUI, or UIKit into the protocol. So whatever is the implementation, it just only needs to conform to the protocol which is only an init with an Item object.

Comment: We can agree to disagree on that one. If you are persisting the View/UIView as you have in your code you are putting the view in the domain. Hence you are forcing the UIView out of your displayer method and you want to do the same with a View. Why don’t you make the displayed type a variable in your model and just show the right view in the switch?

Answer (score 1):

Make `ItemDisplayer` conform to `View`. This is so you can use it like a normal `View`.

```
public protocol ItemDisplayer: View {
    init(item: ItemObject)
}
```

And then change `ItemWithDisplay` so you can use `ItemDisplayer` (because it now has associated type requirements):

```
public struct ItemWithDisplay<Displayer: ItemDisplayer> {
    private let item:  ItemObject
    private let itemDisplayer : Displayer

    public init(item : ItemObject, displayer : Displayer) {
        self.item = item
        self.itemDisplayer = displayer
    }

    public func getDisplayer() -> Displayer {
        return itemDisplayer
    }

    public func getItem() -> ItemObject {
        return item
    }
}
```

Finally, you can now use `getDisplayer()` to get the view, without even needing to convert it to an `AnyView`:

```
VStack {
    item.getDisplayer()
}
```

However, to make something an `AnyView`, you would do the following:

```
VStack {
    AnyView(item.getDisplayer())
}
```

Comment: I thought the same soluton, but the problem with this is that I have to import the SwiftUI package into the protocol (because of : View). For me, the point would be to keep the protocol UI framework independent. I edited the original post with a previous UIKit usage. I'm looking for the answer to whether if the application is written in UIKit on one platform and SwiftUI on the other, I can use the same protocol.